# How to differentiate a click and button click and non buttonclick using js codecode

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where phone number and the dial button appears to be in the same cell of a table . When clicking on the Dial button I should retrieve the phone number in the same cell . This table has dynamically populated and passing this on onclick to javascript is just getting null in js . So I tried the following code instead of the onclick button. The following js code works fine , But it is getting executed clicking anywhere on the cell and not just button . I want to restrict that click to button click . Is there a way to differentiate it ? I cannot use jquery and only want javascript solution since our app is old.

```
</script>
<script language="javascript">
var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable1");
if (tbl != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        tbl.rows[i].cells[0].onclick = function() {
            var x = this.cells.item(0).innerHTML;
            alert(x);
            var res = x.substr(0, 10);
            alert(res);
            makeCalltoPatient(res);
        }
    }
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
```

html code

```
 <c:forEach items="${contactInfoTabl}" var="element"
                            varStatus="status">
                            <tr id="somerow">
                               <td style="text-align: left" class="ValCntr" id="mytd">
                                  <c:out value="${element.number}" />
                                  <input type="button" class="otherButton" value="Dial" />
                               </td>
```

Comment: Can you add a small chunk of the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl.rows[i].cells[0].onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') { ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , But I am getting an error like "Unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference" My html code

<tr id="somerow">
                           <td style="text-align: left" class="ValCntr" id="mytd">
      <c:out value="${element.number}" />
                              <input type="button" class="otherButton" value="Dial"/>
                           </td>

Comment: make sure you included "e" into function arguments to be `function(e)`

Comment: yes I did it . I am using IE 11 and I came to know that target property is not supported by IE and I also tried using srcElement , somehow e is null .

Comment: IE11 supports e.target and onclick binds like you have, you can easily test it by entering this in F12 developer console:
`$('body').html('<div id="test"><button>test</button></div>');
document.getElementById('test').onclick=function(e){console.log(e.target);}`

Comment: inside your function before all other code include this line: `var ev = e ? e : window.event;` and then use `ev` variable to reverence current event object.

Comment: tbl.rows[i].cells[0].onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') { ... This one worked finally , I just changed the value'button' to 'Input' and it gone to the loop , Thank you so much Max Deepfield, and thank you everyone for other suggessions as well .

Comment: For some reason again e.target.tagName is coming null or undefined in IE . Any suggestions please

Comment: but exactly null or undefined?

Comment: I hope it was null and it seems that IE having problems with the code so I used like below and it worked both in IE and chrome 
<script language="javascript">
       var tbl = document.getElementById("patRecordsTable1");
       if (tbl != null) 
      {  
          for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) 
          {              
         tbl.rows[i].cells[0].onclick = function (e) {
     if(!e)
           e = window.event;
   
    target = (e.currentTarget) ? e.target : e.srcElement;                  
       if(target.tagName =='INPUT') 
    {